# Entity Framework Select Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a table with the following data:

> ID  Time and Date Stamp
>
> 3 19/04/2016 21:29:23
>
> 3 19/04/2016 21:35:40
>
> 3 19/04/2016 21:36:26

ID is a foreign key to a table named user with all the details of the user.

Every time they login, the ID and the time of the login is saved to the usersession table:

When I query the table using Linq Statements:

```
int id = 3;
using (var context = new UserContext())
{
    var sessionQuery = context.loginSession.Where(r => r.Id == id);

    return View(sessionQuery.ToList());
}
```

the view is as follows:

```
model IEnumerable<MyFirstWebSite.Models.UserLoginSessionRecords>

foreach (var item in Model) {
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserLoginTimeAndDate)
}
```

I get this in return:

> 3 19/04/2016 21:29:23
>
> 3 19/04/2016 21:29:23
>
> 3 19/04/2016 21:29:23

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you verified that Model contains the data you are expecting? Have you defined a custom template which DisplayFor uses to render the item?

Comment: What do you mean by *By the way stackoverflow make it more and more tedious to reference the using statements and comments*?

Comment: Have you defined a PK for your entity (table)? EF is known to produce duplicate results for mapped db tables/views w/o PK defined.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Visual studio Express 2015 is the version.   

I have defined it as a foreign key for the Usersession Table as it will record the same ID more than once.  The main User Table as a primary key.

The answer to the question from "BanksySan" : Stackoverflow would not allow me to include Razor synthax or comments in my example

Comment: when you debug, are the values that are stuffed into `var sessionQuery` variable what you expect?

Comment: Hi Bville_Kid:  I get the same values when I step through and debug, not sure why

Comment: so your `sessionQuery` variable only contains `3 19/04/2016 21:29:23` 3 times?

Comment: Correct, It iterates through three times but still returns the one timestamp 3 times

Comment: sounds like you need a `foreach` loop to iterate.. so foreach value in the list where id = 3.. and so on and so on

Comment: Try this :  @Html.DisplayFor(item.UserLoginTimeAndDate).  Why do you need modelItem?

Comment: Raw sql query gives me the same issue           


 using (UserContext context = new UserContext())
            {
                var LoginSession = context.loginSession.SqlQuery("Select *                from [dbo].[UserSession] where Id = 3");
                return View(LoginSession.ToList());
            }

I queried the DB directly and I got my results back correctly.  Someone must have come across this issue before :(

Comment: Based upon your comments it appears that the cshtml view is merely displaying the values returned by the EF query. If this is true then please edit the question to remove any discussion of how the data is displayed. It is important to focus on the core of the problem you are encountering. As it is, the question is mixing two separate concerns.

Comment: I understand your comment.  I thought it was best just to have all info out there rather than omitting anything.  Has anyone come across an issue like this before?